# Why does Precision always equal Recall at Threshold 0.5?

Tags: classification, threshold, precision

I ran a few models through Google AutoML Natural Language Single-Label Classification. When I get to the evaluation page, I always see that the precision and recall are equal at a threshold of 0.5. There are only two labels in the dataset - `0`, and `1`. And this precision=recall behavior is something I've seen consistently in the two-label case.

[image: Evaluation Page in Google Cloud Console]

Any idea why this happens? I can't think of a proof that precision should equal recall at a 0.5 threshold.

Comment: I found this page from the documentation that does a very good job of explaining what is happening under the hood: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/beginners-guide#how-do-i-interpret-the-model's-output

Comment: Essentially, the system assigns a score for each category (in my case, that is just two categories, `0` and `1`). Now, from reading the documentation, it's my understanding that each of the two categories should get a threshold slider...but this isn't the case in my UI. I'm guessing this is because the category `0` is assumed to be the 'default' or 'null' category. So...yeah....still don't know where to go from there...